Cannot convert value "IsVisible" to "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableProperty"
When creating a .NET MAUI SingleProject App, I am trying to implement some XAML code, but I can't compile it and get a strange builderror.
This is exactely what I do. In my XAML file I have this peace of code:
<maui:IconButton
    ...some Properties
    >
    <maui:IconButton.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type maui:IconButton}">
          <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding LokalBearbeitet, Mode=OneWay}"
                    TargetType="{x:Type maui:IconButton}"
                    Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </maui:IconButton.Style>
</maui:IconButton>

The definition of IconButton is as follows:
public class IconButton : ImageButton
{
    // Necessary implementation...

The IsVisible Property is defined in namespace Microsoft.Maui.Controls:
public partial class VisualElement ...
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(VisibilityConverter))]
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsVisibleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, value); }
    }


When I compile this code, I get the following error:
Error XFC0040: Cannot convert value "IsVisible" to "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableProperty".
I'm going completely crazy with it. What could be the reason for this mysterious behavior?


Is IconButton a custom control? 2. Have you tried defined the IsVisible as a bindable property to see if it works?


@Alexandar: 1. It extends the fuctionality of ImageButton with some properties. Is this the definition of custom control? I'm not realy sure... If you whant, yes it is. 2. How you can see the implementation of IsVisible in VisualElement, it is already implemented as a bindable property.

This looks like is related with the version of Microsoft.Maui.Controls, please revert back to 8.0.14 which works well.

Was this issue already reported to the MAUI team?

I see this problem with Microsoft.Maui.Controls versions 8.0.20 & 8.0.21.
If you set the version to 8.0.14, things bind properly.  I hope a package update gets released soon.

Oh, that makes sense and could actually be the cause of the problem. I'll give it a try and write back if I've had any success. Many thanks for the tip!

Yes, you were right! The error is actually in the subsequent versions. I downgraded from 8.0.21 to 8.0.14 and the problems were gone.
Thank you very much!

Define it as a BindableProperty
public static readonly BindableProperty IsVisibleProperty =
  BindableProperty.Create ("IsVisible", typeof(bool), typeof(IconButton), false);

public bool IsVisible
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(IsVisibleProperty);
    set => SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, value);
}

and then use it when you call the IconButton in xaml binding to the IsVisible property

If you take a look into the class Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement you can see, IsVisible is allready a bindable property =)
